# Calculate the fixed field of these automorphisms

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, functional-equations, rational-functions, automorphism-group

> Let $k$ be a field, and let $K = k(x)$ be the rational function field in one variable over $k$. Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be the automorphisms of $K$ defined by $\sigma(f(x)/g(x)) = f(1/x)/g(1/x)$ and $\tau(f(x)/g(x)) = f(1-x)/g(1-x)$, respectively. Determine the fixed field $F$ of $\{\sigma,\tau\}$, and determine $\mathrm{Gal}(K/F)$. Find an $h \in F$ so that $F = k(h)$.

I tried to equate $\sigma(f), \tau(f)$ and $f$ to come up with some conditions, but it didn't really help. So, what is the goto methodology / thought process when solving these kind of problems? Where do I start?

**Edit :** From the conversation I had in the comments, it seems that $F$ might be the collection of $f/g$ where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials of the same degree with symmetric coefficients.

Comment: Note that $\sigma (x^n)=x^{-n}$. What does this tell us about the fixed field?

Comment: @CyclotomicField That it doesn't have non-constant polynomials?

Comment: That's correct but I would just call it the constants rather than not having the non-constant polynomials. Can you find the inverse of this automorphism?

Comment: @CyclotomicField It's the inverse of itself. Both are.

Comment: @CyclotomicField But there might be non-constant rational functions, no?

Comment: Yes but the fixed field doesn't contain any of those as you mentioned before.

Comment: @CyclotomicField It doesn't contain non-constant polynomials. The same cannot be said about rational functions in general. For example, $x^2+1 \over x^2+x+1$ is fixed by $\sigma$.

Comment: We can say that $f$ and $g$ must have same degree though.

Comment: Might it help to observe that $k(x+\frac{1}{x})$ is fixed by $\sigma$? Also, when I look at $\sigma, \tau$ I am reminded of cross-ratios and the six values one gets by permuting the four points.

Comment: @ancientmathematician In general, it works for $f$ and $g$ of same degree where both have symmetric coefficients.

Comment: Actually, that might just be it. (Check edit)

Comment: I think the way I wrote it is better, it gives the generator of the fixed field of $\sigma$ [Surely?]. Likewise for $\tau$ isn't the fixed field $k( (x-\frac{1}{2})^2)$? I think that $\langle\sigma,\tau\rangle$ is $S_3$  and that it is easy by trial and error to work out the six images of $x$ - as I said it's just like doing the cross-ratios calculation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think yes. Thanks.

Comment: And even before that the questions was studied [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1041275/11619).